# Parsing XML document that includes another XML document embedded in a CDATA section

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I'm trying out web scraping for the first time using `lxml.etree`. The website I want to scrape has an XML feed, which I can read fine, except for a part of its XML which is embedded within a CDATA section:

```py
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

data=b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
  <entry>
    <summary type="xhtml"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <REMITUrgentMarketMessages>
            <UMM>
                <messageId>2023-86___________________001</messageId>
                <event>
                    <eventStatus>Active</eventStatus>
                    <eventType>Other unavailability</eventType>
                    <eventStart>2023-09-07T06:00:00.000+02:00</eventStart>
                    <eventStop>2023-09-10T06:00:00.000+02:00</eventStop>
                </event>
                <unavailabilityType>Planned</unavailabilityType>
                <publicationDateTime>2022-10-06T13:42:00.000+02:00</publicationDateTime>
                <capacity>
                    <unitMeasure>mcm/d</unitMeasure>
                    <unavailableCapacity>9.0</unavailableCapacity>
                    <availableCapacity>0.0</availableCapacity>
                    <technicalCapacity>9.0</technicalCapacity>
                </capacity>
                <unavailabilityReason>Yearly maintenance</unavailabilityReason>
                <remarks>Uncertain duration</remarks>
                <balancingZone>21Y000000000024I</balancingZone>
                <balancingZone>21Y0000000001278</balancingZone>
                <balancingZone>21YGB-UKGASGRIDW</balancingZone>
                <balancingZone>21YNL----TTF---1</balancingZone>
                <balancingZone>37Y701125MH0000I</balancingZone>
                <balancingZone>37Y701133MH0000P</balancingZone>
                <affectedAsset>
                    <ns2:name>Dvalin</ns2:name>
                </affectedAsset>
                <marketParticipant>
                    <ns2:name>Gassco AS</ns2:name>
                    <ns2:eic>21X-NO-A-A0A0A-2</ns2:eic>
                </marketParticipant>
            </UMM>
        </REMITUrgentMarketMessages>]]></summary>
  </entry>
</feed>
'''

tree = etree.fromstring(data)
block = tree.xpath("/feed/entry/summary")[0]

block_str = "b'''"+block.text+"'''"

tree_in_tree = etree.fromstring(block_str)
```

The problem the XML code in the CDATA section is weirdly indented, meaning that if I just pass the CDATA content into a string and then read it with etree (like I do below), I get a message error because of indentation.

This is the message:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Basically I understand that the indentation between the first line of CDATA and REMITUrgentMarketMessages is badly indented.

Does anyone know how to fix this? :)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b` prefix is used for *bytes literals*, but `block.text` is not a literal. Instead, create the bytes object (representing the embedded XML document) using `bytes()`:

```py
block_str = bytes(block.text, "UTF-8")
```

Now when the program is run, you will get the following error:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix ns2 on name is not defined

That is a serious error, but it can be bypassed by using the `parser` configured with `recover=True`:

```py
tree_in_tree = etree.fromstring(block_str, parser)
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with indentation. The problem is that the xml within the CDATA is not well formed. It uses namespaces (`<ns2:name>Gassco AS</ns2:name>`, for example), [but without a namespace declaration](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). So when you try to parse `block.text` you should get

```
XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix ns2 on name is not defined
```

at least based on the xml in the question. Not sure why you get the error you are showing.

The solution is to ask the source of the feed to fix the xml so it's well formed.

Comment: It is correct that the `ns2` namespace prefix is undeclared in the XML document inside the CDATA section. But the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces is about Python namespaces. It is not about XML namespaces.